# Swift Dataqueue

Tags: arrays, swift

I need a class where I can store objects in a stack and when adding one, remove items, which are older than a predefined treshold.

I want to store data each 30 milli seconds in that array (with a timestamp).
When adding a new data object I would like to remove all objects which exceed the treshold from their timestamp and the one which was recently added or will be added.
I created a class with an array of class `DataQueueObject` (this class has a variable timestamp).

Now, when pushing a new item, first it checks if there are items in it, then starting from the last, removing it, if it exceeds the maximumQueueTime which is my interval variable

```
private (set) var objects : [DataQueueObject] = [DataQueueObject](); 
private let maximumQueueTime : Double;

func push(item : DataQueueObjects) {
    while(objects.count > 0) {
        let da : DataQueueObjects = objects.last!;
        if((item.timestamp - da.timestamp) > maximumQueueTime) {
            objects.removeLast()
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    objects.append(item);
}
```

My problem now is that sometimes `objects.removeLast` result in a 
fatal error:

> Array replace: subRange extends past the end

Comment: I can't reproduce: a loop on `while(objects.count > 0)` where we `removeLast()` doesn't crash for me. Can you provide a complete verifiable working example?

Comment: Are you calling those methods from multiple threads?

Comment: Core Data Concurrency.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Comment: yes these dataqueues are called from different threads. the data comes from the phones sensors and are sent by nsnotificationscenter.defaultcenter(). a singleton class is listening to these and fills the queue. how can i achieve thread safety in this case?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191079/create-thread-safe-array-in-swift or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784507/adding-items-to-swift-array-across-multiple-threads-causing-issues-because-arra.

Comment: based on these links from Martin R a objc_sync_enter(lock) at the beginning and objc_sync_exit(lock) at the end of the method would fix that problem?