# Is DispatchSemaphore a good replacement for NSLock?

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift3

I've been using `NSLock`s to synchronize touchy parts of code, but have been running into issues due to the fact that they must be unlocked from the same thread that they were locked from. Then I found that GCD's `DispatchSemaphore`s seem to do the same thing, with the added convenience that they can be signaled from any thread. I was wondering, though, if this convenience comes at the price of thread-safety. Is it advisable to replace

```
let lock = NSLock()
lock.lock()
// do things...
lock.unlock()
```

with

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
semaphore.wait()
// do things...
semaphore.signal()
```

or will I run into issues regarding thread-safety anyway?

Comment: Still haven't gotten an answer, but another reason I would prefer to use Semaphores is that it's safe to "unlock" them even when they're not "locked".

Comment: `DispatchSemaphore` has one flaw – it's available since iOS10.0.

Comment: @kelin in documentation there is iOS 8.0 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they have the same function, both to deal with producer-consumer problem.

Semaphore allows more than one thread to access a shared resource if it is configured accordingly. You can make the execution of the blocks in the same concurrent dispatchQueue.

```swift
{
    semaphore.wait()
    // do things...
    semaphore.signal()
}
```

Actually the same applies to Lock, if you only want one thread to touch the resource at one time, in the concurrent way.

I found this to be helpful: https://priteshrnandgaonkar.github.io/concurrency-with-swift-3/

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this, I have mostly switched over to another way of locking blocks of code: serial dispatch queues. I use it like this:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "<your label here>")
queue.async {
    // do things...
}
```

The queue is serial by default, meaning it acts as a lock that releases when the block is exited. Therefore, it's not appropriate if you need to lock on an asynchronous operation, but it works a charm in most cases.

Comment: You can also use that with a barrier sync to lock when needed (i.e. writes can block reads until they complete). Decent examples in https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

Comment: Don't do this. Completely unnecessary. A single semaphore has much less overhead. You create a queue that is 1) not needed 2) creates stack frames every time you dispatch something 3) captures context.

Comment: @ErikAigner I would create a queue to move work off the main queue, and a semaphore to block the queue while asynchronous work is being done.

Comment: @ErikAigner In many cases, the performance difference is insignificant. You should benchmark your code to see how performance-sensitive it is before worrying too much about this. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.